# Inject module into another module

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two modules: the first module for the map and the other for payment.
I want display the direction between two points A and B of the map in the payment.

I want to know how to inject the module or the controller of the map in the payment

```
'use strict';

(function () {
  'use strict';

  var module = angular.module('etaxi.main');

  module.controller('HomeCtrl', HomeCtrl);

//Controller of map

  function HomeCtrl($scope, $rootScope, $timeout, $ionicPopup, uiGmapGoogleMapApi, $http, $log, $document) {
  //...
})();
```

### Payment controller

```
'use strict';

(function () {
  'use strict';

  var module = angular.module('etaxi.payment');

  module.controller('PaymentCtrl', PaymentCtrl);

  function PaymentCtrl($scope, $ionicModal, $ionicLoading, $timeout, uiGmapGoogleMapApi) {
 //...
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you shouldn't use [implicit-annotation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#implicit-annotation), but you can try [$inject-property-annotation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#-inject-property-annotation) or Inline Array Annotation. All this ways are in official docs: [AngularJS Dependency Injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di).

Your code:

```
 var module = angular.module('etaxi.payment', ['etaxi.main']); 
 module.controller('PaymentCtrl', PaymentCtrl);

  var PaymentCtrl = function($scope, $ionicModal, $ionicLoading, $timeout, uiGmapGoogleMapApi, etaxiMain) {
    ...
  }
  PaymentCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$ionicModal', '$ionicLoading', '$timeout', 'uiGmapGoogleMapApi', 'etaxi.main'];
```

**UPD:** forgot to add: `var module = angular.module('etaxi.payment', ['etaxi.main']);` (was fixed).

Comment: AFAIK, Modules should be injected into other modules, not into controllers.

Comment: @Dave you're right, my mistake. I'll fix it: `var module = angular.module('etaxi.payment', ['etaxi.main']);`

Comment: @HafedhMahmoudi you're welcome :) mark answer as correct if it solved a question.